# Responsive table using Angular and angular-responsive-tables

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to make a responsive table using AngularJS.

I created a fiddle showing what I want to do: https://jsfiddle.net/loredano/xnyzaLnu/1/

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products" >
    <td data-title='{{titles.col1}}'>{{product.id}}</td>
    <td data-title='{{titles.col2}}'>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td data-title='{{titles.col3}}'>{{product.col3}}</td>
    <td data-title='{{titles.col4}}'>{{product.col4}}</td>
    <td data-title='{{titles.col5}}'>{{product.col5}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is more or less what I'm trying to do. I want to be able to populate the data-title getting the data from my $scope.titles.
I'm new with Angular and with front-end programming. Is there another way I could accomplish it?

I'm using this angular-responsive-tables https://github.com/awerlang/angular-responsive-tables to do the css "trick".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem you have in your fiddle for your approach to work is that your $scope.titles is an array, not an object. If you want it to work, just remove the square brackets.

```
$scope.titles = {
  col1: "Id", 
  col2: "Name", 
  col3: "Something", 
  col4: "Something else", 
  col5: "Something something"
};
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xnyzaLnu/2/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it solved my problem! The only problem with your fidde was that you forgot the 'data' before 'title'. Now it works perfectly! Thank you very much!